# `more.com` returns "Not enough memory."

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, powershell-5.0

Environment details:

- x64 Win7 SP1 Enterprise
- Windows PowerShell v5.0

---

Without any profiles loaded, my local [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) sessions are returning

> Not enough memory.

when I try to execute `help` or `man`.  This occurs whether I'm using the native `powershell.exe` or [conemu](/questions/tagged/conemu).

Strangely, I am able to execute any other aliases I've tried, and it doesn't add to the `$Error` variable, so I have no idea where to start troubleshooting (I've tried `-ErrorAction Stop` and `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`).

As a footnote, I don't have any elevated privileges.

---

After some exploration, I found that `man` is actually an alias for `help` which isn't an alias for `Get-Help`, but a function of its own with this definition:

```
function help {
<#
.FORWARDHELPTARGETNAME Get-Help
.FORWARDHELPCATEGORY Cmdlet
#>
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'AllUsersView', HelpUri = 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113316')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]
        ${Name},

        [string]
        ${Path},

        [ValidateSet('Alias', 'Cmdlet', 'Provider', 'General', 'FAQ', 'Glossary', 'HelpFile', 'ScriptCommand', 'Function', 'Filter', 'ExternalScript', 'All', 'DefaultHelp', 'Workflow', 'DscResource', 'Class', 'Configuration')]
        [string[]]
        ${Category},

        [string[]]
        ${Component},

        [string[]]
        ${Functionality},

        [string[]]
        ${Role},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'DetailedView', Mandatory = $true)]
        [switch]
        ${Detailed},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AllUsersView')]
        [switch]
        ${Full},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Examples', Mandatory = $true)]
        [switch]
        ${Examples},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Parameters', Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]
        ${Parameter},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Online', Mandatory = $true)]
        [switch]
        ${Online},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ShowWindow', Mandatory = $true)]
        [switch]
        ${ShowWindow}
    )

    #Set the outputencoding to Console::OutputEncoding. More.com doesn't work well with Unicode.
    $outputEncoding = [System.Console]::OutputEncoding

    Get-Help @PSBoundParameters | more
}
```

Even further... `more` is another function:

```
function more {
    param([string[]]$paths)

    $OutputEncoding = [System.Console]::OutputEncoding

    if($paths) {
        foreach ($file in $paths) {
            Get-Content $file | more.com
        }
    }
    else {
        $input | more.com
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, it's only the `help` and `man` commands and `more.com` executable that cause the "Not enough memory" error?  PowerShell otherwise works normally?

Comment: @BACON Correct.  After some additional investigation, it looks to be an encoding issue with `more.com` which persists as long as that console host lives since I changed it to [tag:utf-8] and it doesn't handle multi-byte characters.  I'm going to post a write-up to answer this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A seemingly inherent flaw with `more.com`, it has difficulty handling multi-byte encodings (such as [utf-8](/questions/tagged/utf-8)) and will instead throw a

> Not enough memory.

error.

I don't have enough knowledge to figure out *why* it throws that message or how to replicate it on different systems (for example, I could not replicate on x64 Windows 10 1804 Pro), but it can be remediated by changing the `OutputEncoding` static member on `[System.Console]` to a default encoding (in this case, `CP437`, which was my conhost's default):

```
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(437)
```

or other single-byte encoding, such as `CP1252`.

If this error is being observed in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), it can be remediated using `chcp.com` (untested whether this also updates `[Console]::OutputEncoding`):

```
chcp.com 437
```

---

As a side-note, the code that caused this failure for me is in my `$PROFILE`:

```
[Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = $OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
```

The issues persisted while using the same console host, even after exiting [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) when I was left in a [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) prompt.

---

Edit: for powershell to work, I had to do a combined codepage + `OutputEncoding` change:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(437)
& chcp.com 437
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful! FWIW, if you install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) and make its executable available on the PowerShell PATH, you can use `Get-Help ... | less`, which allows scrolling up and down. (Then, type `q` to quit, or `h` for options; navigation info is always shown at the bottom.) [Less](https://manpage.me/?q=less) is  more! ;-)