# How to run a command with some utf8 parameters in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a command on PowerShell with some Persian text but it is not working as expected.

```
$message = @" 
سلام امین 
"@

& some.exe @('-m',"$message")
```

Unfortunately the text that reaches to some.exe is `Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù… Ø§Ù…ÛŒÙ†` which is clearly wrong.

How to fix this?

**Update:**

Tried this and still not working as expected.

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding

$message = @" 
سلام امین 
"@


Write-Output $message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the @Dabombber answer is correct. but in my case, the problem was that the script file that I have saved on disk was not saved with Unicode encoding. It is strange, cause I used VS Code to write that script and I assumed that VS Code is aware of this.

Anyway, The solution was to open the script with `Powershell ISE` and save it again. That fixed the problem.

Comment: Powershell 5.1 can't recognize utf8 no bom without help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the output encoding as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/11216160).

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```

```
PS> $message = @"
>> سلام امین
>> "@
PS> echoargs $message
Arg 0 is <???? ???? >

Command line:
"C:\Windows\system32\echoargs.exe" "???? ???? "

PS> $OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
PS> echoargs $message
Arg 0 is <سلام امین >

Command line:
"C:\Windows\system32\echoargs.exe" "سلام امین "
```

If you choose to put this in your profile, be aware of the [possible problems it may cause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55250504/11216160).

Comment: How to use this `$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding` in a powershell script?

Comment: @AminSojoudi Put the line in the PowerShell script? If you're worried about resetting it afterwards, there's an example linked in the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/11216160).

Answer (score -1):

The issue is not in PowerShell but in `some.exe`. Strings in PowerShell is always in UTF-16 because .NET has only a single type of string that's encoded in UTF-16. When you call `some.exe` Windows will convert the input parameters to [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) if you use `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. If the Windows code page is not set correctly then you won't be able to get those characters correctly

One solution is to change to [`int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[], wchar_t *envp[]);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=vs-2019) to get Unicode parameters. Or if you must use `main()` for portability then call [`GetCommandLineW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew) to get the Unicode command line then parse it with [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw)

The better solution is to [change to UTF-8 locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/995714). That way it's much easier to port the code to other platforms, and there would be no need to deal with the Unicode/ANSI mess in Windows anymore. Just upgrade the Windows SDK and set the [`/utf8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=vs-2019) flag, along with linking the Windows SDK statically if you need to target older Windows

If changing Windows SDK is not an option then you can use [Boost.Nowide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/nowide/doc/html/index.html) and use UTF-8 everywhere. That way `argv[]` will also be in UTF-8

Comment: The some.exe is not written by me, it's `https://github.com/appleboy/gorush`, and when I use bash to pass utf8 parameters to it everything is fine.